# NetworkInfo return always null

Tags: java, android, connection

I'm having some problems with the Ethernet connection, in particular the NetworkInfo class return always null.

I'm actually using this code:

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); //not null
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET);  //null
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
```

I'm trying to make an Ethernet connection, someone can help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a ethernet interface on the device? Most devices only have WiFi, unless you're using proprietary Android device or usb ethernet dongle.

Comment: Yes, the device has the Ethernet port, I'm not using any type of dongles

Comment: If you use `adb shell ifconfig` do you see a eth0 adapter with an assigned IP address?

Comment: This is the output: eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:A0:B3:E7:16:9F
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 TX bytes:0

Comment: Looks like there is no assigned IP address, and therefore that's why the network comes back null.

Comment: Okay but if I use the same code to check the Wifi connection while I'm not connected to any Wifi network It returns "disconnected" or something like that but not "null". So,  I really not understand why with the Wifi works and with Ethernet not. Thanks for your help

Comment: If you're not getting the ethernet symbol on your status bar (appears where the WiFi icon does) when connected then there is a software problem, potentially the hal driver, as the Android OS is not aware of the presence of ethernet.  If this is a proprietary device chances are it has a custom hal driver.   If you have access to the source code I'd look at that.

Comment: I'll check, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

for Ethernet try as below

```
public Boolean isEthernetConnected(){
    if(isNetworkAvailable()){
        ConnectivityManager cm 
        = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET);
    }
    return false;
}

 private Boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

Comment: This returns active network, not necessarily ethernet, which was the OPs question.

Comment: please check updated ans it will check for Ethernet @MarkKeen

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but it still not working